# Is there a way to have columns in baposter boxes?

Tags: columns, baposter

I'm writing a poster using the baposter style and wondered if it's possible to break boxes up into columns?

Comment: Maybe using a table? Or minipages? Or minipages in a table? It would help if you could show some code of the setup of the poster and the contents you want to put in the columns.

Comment: You can use `multicols` inside a box. Several `baposter` examples in the distribution have that.